# Cutting a String variable with regex

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have this String variable:

```
 String a = "Chris Weitz (screenplay), Tony Gilroy (screenplay) Lucasfilm Allison Shearmur Productions Black Hangar Studios";
```

It can contain one or two "Name Surename (job)" pattern seperated with a comma.

How to use regex successfull to cut of everything but these patterns? It should look like this in the end:

```
a = "Chris Weitz (screenplay), Tony Gilroy (screenplay)";
```

or like this:

```
a = "Chris Weitt (screenplay)";
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: if you are really sure of comma separated you can use `a.split(",")` it will return array of strings as `Chris Weitt (screenplay)`

Comment: The problem is, this will only work with for one "Name Surename (Job" Pattern. The second one is never seperated with a comma.

Comment: what you've tried? basically you want to remove any other string but the one that match `([[:alpha:] ]+\([[:alpha:]]+\))`?

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "Chris Weitz (screenplay), Tony Gilroy (screenplay) Lucasfilm Allison Shearmur Productions Black Hangar Studios";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^,\\(]+\\([^\\)]+\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group().trim());
}
```

Comment: While that code does work, you should consider adding at least a brief explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Remove (ie replace with blank) everything from the last `)` onward:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\)[^)]*$", ")");
```

The regex matches a closing bracket through to the end without encountering another closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating Gurwinder Singh answer a bit.. (and changing the regex pattern)

```
String s = "Chris Weitz (screenplay), Tony Gilroy (screenplay) Lucasfilm Allison Shearmur Productions Black Hangar Studios";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([[:alpha:] ]+\\([[:alpha:]]+\\))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group().trim());
}
```

The idea is to match a string with given pattern - `([[:alpha:] ]+\([[:alpha:]]+\))` - that basically captures any word that followed by a pair of brackets. - [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EnZT48/1)